# Beamer: Synchronize overlays for itemized list items in presentation slide and notes slide

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

I am making a presentation using `Beamer` and I would like for most of my slides to have an `itemize` list on the presentation slide that is uncovered using the `<+->` style. On the associated notes slide, I would like pretty much the same list, just more wordy, and uncovered in a synchronized fashion. I tried to do this using the code below, but for some reason the first two notes appear at the same time (i.e. with the first presentation item), then when I get to the last presentation item, all items on the notes slide disappear.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Naive HDR Combination}

\begin{itemize}
        \item My first point
                \note[item]{A note about my first point}
        \item My second point
                \note[item]{A note about my second point}
        \item My third point
                \note[item]{A note about my third point}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get this working? I realize I can manually set slide numbers for each `\note`, e.g. `\note[item]<2->`,  but a) that's irritating and b) if I later decide to add a new item mid-list, I have to renumber all following notes. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't explain *exactly* the behaviour that you are seeing, but my experiments lead me to conclude that it is coming from an interaction between the `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` command and the rest of the set-up.  What appears to be happening is that the `\item`s that appear in the list in the notes **are sensitive to the overlay**.  So they inherit the setting of `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification`.  Your list of notes is thus equivalent to:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item<+-> A note about my first point
\item<+-> A note about my second point
\item<+-> A note about my third point
\end{enumerate}
```

Where this gets confusing is exactly how the overlays are determined on the `note` slide.  This I don't quite understand.

The `\note<overlay>` specification works by putting the note command in an `\only` at the point of call.  So that is independent of the behaviour in the note slide.  Indeed, I'd be tempted to call it a bug that `\item` is overlay-aware in the notes.

So when using notes, I would recommend *not* using `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification`.  To get the same effect, you can put `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`.

This still doesn't solve your problem, though, as that now means that the all the notes for a frame appear on every slide of that frame.  One way to fix this which avoids the issue you refer to is to write `\note<.->[item]{note text}`.  The `<.->` syntax means "from this slide on" (NB: outside an itemize, you might have to offset it by 1, so `\note<.(1)->[item]{note text}`.)  This at least fixes issue (b) with specifying an explicit overlay since then reordering the list also reorders the notes.

To remove the necessity for using *any* overlay specification, one could hack the `\note` command so that it took a *default* overlay specification.  We'd want to be sure that it wasn't the same as that set by the `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` as we don't want it to interfere with the normal operation of the frame.  Here's a working example, but I don't guarantee that it works in all situations!

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28972/86}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}

\makeatletter
\def\beamerdefaultnoteoverlay#1{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}%
  {%
    \def\beamer@gdefaultnotespec{<*>}%
    \def\beamer@defaultnotespec{<*>}}%
  {%
    \def\beamer@gdefaultnotespec{#1}%
    \def\beamer@defaultnotespec{#1}%
  }%
}
\beamerdefaultnoteoverlay{}

%% Hack to avoid bug in \renewcommand (fixed in latest version)
 \expandafter\let\csname beamerx@\string\beamer@inframenote\endcsname\relax
 \newcommand<>{\beamer@inframenote}[2][]{%
   \ifbeamer@inlecture%
  \beamer@ifempty{#3}%
  {%
   \let\note@ospec=\beamer@defaultnotespec
  }{%
   \def\note@ospec{#3}%
  }%
     \expandafter\only\note@ospec{%
       \def\beamer@temp{#1}%
       \ifx\beamer@temp\beamer@itemtext%
         \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@noteitems%
         \expandafter{\beamer@noteitems\item#2}%
       \else
         \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@notes%
           \expandafter{\beamer@notes#2}%
       \fi%
     }%
   \fi%
   }
\makeatother

\beamerdefaultnoteoverlay{<.->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Naive HDR Combination}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item My first point
                \note[item]{A note about my first point}
        \item My second point
                \note[item]{A note about my second point}
        \item My third point
                \note[item]{A note about my third point}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```