# Beamer overlay notes: last note missing

Tags: beamer, overlays, notes

I'm trying to get notes to appear sequentially on the notes page in sync with bullets on the main slide. For some reason the last note text never appears:

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen = right}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
\note<1->[item]{Something}
\note<2->[item]{Something else}
\note<3->[item]{And something completely different}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This only happens when I use a default overlay specification `<+->`

Related: [Beamer: Synchronize overlays for itemized list items in presentation slide and notes slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28972/beamer-synchronize-overlays-for-itemized-list-items-in-presentation-slide-and-n)

Answer (score 3):

I moved the `[<+->]` specification to the `itemize` environment and all starts working again. I think this is the best solution since this way whenever you should need another frame option (eg fragile) you could specify it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen = right}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
\note<1->[item]{Something}
\note<2->[item]{Something else}
\note<3->[item]{And something completely different}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The same result is obtained specifying the overlay *inside* the `itemize` environment

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen = right}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item One
\note<1->[item]{Something}
\item Two
\note<2->[item]{Something else}
\item Three
\note<3->[item]{And something completely different}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So - is this a bug in how the overlay logic?