# beamer notes on animated pages

Tags: beamer, notes

I have animated slides and I am trying to generate notes to go along with them. Unfortunately, I get the notes after the last animation in the frame and not with every animation. I would like to get a notes page right after each animation. Is there a way to do that?

Also, is there a way to animate the notes as well so they come right after the frame they are related with? As the attached figure shows, I only get the first two items in the notes, but not the rest.

The following is a MWE and the output.

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,usenames,dvipsnames,aspectratio=149, 11.5pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{lily}

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\pagecolor{yellow!5}\insertnote}\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Graphs have become ubiquitous}
    
    \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{graph-market.jpg}}
    
    %\vspace{1cm}
    
    \uncover<2->{
        \vspace{-2.2in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graph-market-2.jpg}
    }
    
    \uncover<3->{
        \vspace{-2.7in}
        
        \hfill
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graph-market-1.jpg}
    }
    
    \uncover<4>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \shade[shading=axis,
        top color=blue!60,
        bottom color=blue!60,
        %middle color=red,
        shading angle=30 %????
        ]
        %       (current page.west)--++(15:1.2\paperwidth)--++(0,-2cm) --([yshift=-2cm]current page.west)--cycle node\[right,rotate=15,xshift=2cm,yshift=-1cm] {\Huge \alert{D\'ej\`a vu all over again?}};
        (current page.west)--++(0:1.2\paperwidth)--++(0,-1cm) --([yshift=-1cm]current page.west)--cycle node[right,xshift=5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] {\Large \textcolor{White}{CAGR $>$ 20\%}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    
\end{frame}



\note{%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Verified Market Research: Right now the market is \$781M
        \item<1-> Verified Market Research: It will be \$4.13B by 2026
        \item<2-> MarketsandMarkets prediction: \$2.4B by 2023 (in the slides)
        \item<3-> Gartner expects 100\% growth annually through 2022
        \item<4> Cumulative Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) > 20\% -- expectation by almost everyone
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out based on [Beamer overlay notes: last note missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373632/beamer-overlay-notes-last-note-missing). Basically the notes need to go inside the animation with some additions.

First the preamble needs to be revised as:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=top}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\pagecolor{yellow!5}\insertnote}
```

Then the notes have to be itemized within the frame definition as follows:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Graphs have become ubiquitous}
    
    \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{graph-market.jpg}}
    
    %\vspace{1cm}
    
    \uncover<2->{
        \vspace{-2.2in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graph-market-2.jpg}
    }
    
    \uncover<3->{
        \vspace{-2.7in}
        
        \hfill
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{graph-market-1.jpg}
    }
    
    \uncover<4>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \shade[shading=axis,
        top color=blue!60,
        bottom color=blue!60,
        %middle color=red,
        shading angle=30 %????
        ]
        %       (current page.west)--++(15:1.2\paperwidth)--++(0,-2cm) --([yshift=-2cm]current page.west)--cycle node[right,rotate=15,xshift=2cm,yshift=-1cm] {\Huge \alert{D\'ej\`a vu all over again?}};
        (current page.west)--++(0:1.2\paperwidth)--++(0,-1cm) --([yshift=-1cm]current page.west)--cycle node[right,xshift=5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] {\Large \textcolor{White}{CAGR $>$ 20\%}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    
    \note<1->[item]{Verified Market Research: Right now the market is \$781M}
    \note<1->[item]{Verified Market Research: It will be \$4.13B by 2026}
    \note<2->[item]{MarketsandMarkets prediction: \$2.4B by 2023 (in the slides)}
    \note<3->[item]{Gartner expects 100\% growth annually through 2022}
    \note<4->[item]{Cumulative Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) $>$ 20\% -- expectation by almost everyone}
\end{frame}
```

Now it works. By the way, no `\note{...}` after the `\end{frame}`.

Two things that I still need to figure out (suggestions would be much welcome):

1. I cannot get it to work with `show notes on second screen=bottom`; if anyone has any ideas?...
2. I need to figure out how to get the notes not to be in plain (although this is really minor).

Comment: "need to figure out how to get the notes not to be in plain" – do you mean `\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]` ?

Comment: I had really forgotten this since I posted it. I need to go and check to see what I am getting and what I meant.